# Is there any way to make it -> snapshot.data[index].variable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

In flutter if i wanted to print the values using FutureBuilder
I have to write this 3 line individually
**snapshot.data[index].courseName** ,
**snapshot.data[index].coursePrice**,
**snapshot.data[index].aboutCourse**

```
So, Is there any way to make a list like this -> fieldItem = ['courseName' , 'coursePrice' , 'aboutCourse'] and then pass fieldItems after the .data[index].{our varibles}
**snapshot.data[index].fieldItems**
varibles will be passed through the fieldItem.
```

**Sorry for my bad english**

Comment: Can you include your current futureBuilder

Answer (score 0):

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadData(),
        builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) { 
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            // You can make variable here
            // final _data = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                      // Or as in your case
                      final _data = snapshot.data![index];
                      return Card(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        // render list item
                        child: ListTile(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          title: Text(_data['title']),
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data![index]['body']),
                      ),
                    ),
                    }
                  ); 
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        }
      );
```

Refer 11th line, if it helps, upvote.

Comment: It is always preferred to cast `snapshot.data` to actual type. E.g.: `final _data = snapshot.data as List<String>;`